# Radare2 find xrefs to a function in the import table

Tags: radare2

What is the Radare2 equivalent of going to the import table in ida, hitting enter on a function and then pressing ctrl+x?

When I use axt, it can only find xrefs to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some researching.

I ran aaa and now you can use axt @ sym.imp.[dll].[function]